# I want view FBX file in ubuntu using opengl

Tags: c++, ubuntu, opengl, fbx

can i open the FBX file using opengl?
I want just view FBX file.
I did ViewScene project that fbx sdk sample. but i can't compile project...

so, How do view FBX file using opengl in ubuntu 14.04?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenGL has nothing relates to FBX. FBX is a format of file to store 3D scenes. OpenGL is a rendering API. You can read FBX file (with [FBX SDK](http://www.autodesk.com/products/fbx/overview) for example) create a scene (by your own) and then render it using OpenGL API.